# access a function within a javascript file with capybara/selenium

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, capybara

I am kind of new to the whole selenium and capybara and I hope I can get some guidance.  I am currently trying to access a function within a JSP file that is contained in a frameset but I am not having any luck on figuring this out.

Basically i went to navigate the jsp file from a frame

```
<FRAME name="sideFrame" src="AppMenu.jsp" noresize="yes" scrolling="no"
```

to a function within that file that has this:

```
 <a onclick="nav_swap(this.id)" class="nav" id="view_new_page" href="javascript:submitWithAction('ViewNewPage', 'view_new_page');">View New Page /a>
```

I have looked into xpath and within_frame but I don't think that will help me with this problem that I am facing.

This is kind of what I have at the moment:

```
session.find(:xpath,"//FRAME[@src='AppMenu.jsp']/..").all(:xpath,".//A[@id='view_new_page']/..").click
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must first call [select_frame](http://selenium-client.rubyforge.org/classes/Selenium/Client/GeneratedDriver.html#M000150) for the targeted iframe, then use selectors within that context.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I was looking into within_frame some more and was able to figure out what I was doing wrong. I just put it in a block and it worked.

Comment: session.within_frame('sideFrame') do 
  session.click_on 'View New Page 
  sleep 10 
end

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. :)  If you found my answer helpful, consider upvoting or accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

hm. Not so far I came across with getting element's property. I used js for it.
Code example provided:

```
public String jsGetColor(String css){

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x=$(\'"+css+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("return x.css('color')");
        String res= (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
        return res;

    }
```

Hope this gives you some fresh idea.